# Angular material slider cannot show values

Tags: angular, typescript, slider, angular-material

I want to show to have a slider with angular material library. 
The goal here is that when i slide to choose the amount of users on a subscription the price dynamically changes when i slide back or forwards.

I can set the values in my ts component but it does not dynamically changes in the html, but i did double binding brackets {{}}. i am a little bit confused why it does not works.

**subscriptioncomponent.html**

```
<h1>Subscription</h1>
<h5>Choose how much user your account will have</h5>
<h5> {{amount}} Euro/month</h5>
<h5>{{user}} Users</h5>
<mat-slider 
  thumbLabel
  [displayWith]="formatLabel"
  tickInterval="auto"
  min="1"
  max="10"
  [(ngModel)]="value"></mat-slider>
```

**subscriptioncomponent.ts**

```
      export class SubscriptionchooseComponent implements OnInit {
      amount : number = 0;
      user : number = 0;
      value: number = 1;

      formatLabel(value: number | null) {
        if (!value) {
          return 0;
        }
        this.value = value;
        console.log(this.value);

        return value;
      }

      constructor() {

        this.user = this.value;
        this.amount = this.user * 9;

        console.log(this.amount);
        console.log(this.value);
       } 

      ngOnInit() {

      }

}
```

Comment: Lets try my answer also. Its working perfect tested and also you have got value both html and ts side. You can use further..

Comment: hi , i tried it. it works but the solution i checked is simpler and does what i need. but thank you for your solution aswell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
<h1>Subscription</h1>
<h5>Choose how much user your account will have</h5>
<h5> {{value * 9}} Euro/month</h5>
<h5>{{value}} Users</h5>
<mat-slider thumbLabel tickInterval="auto" min="1" max="10" [(ngModel)]="value"></mat-slider>
```

If you need access to the value in your component you can bind to `input()`:

```
<h1>Subscription</h1>
<h5>Choose how much user your account will have</h5>
<h5> {{amount}} Euro/month</h5>
<h5>{{user}} Users</h5>
<mat-slider thumbLabel tickInterval="auto" min="1" max="10" (input)="changeValue($event)"></mat-slider>
```

and in your component:

```
changeValue(event) {
    this.user = event.value;
    this.amount = event.value * 9;
}
```

Comment: this is working , thank you sir. Could you tell why my solution was not working it almost seems the same ...

Comment: Well, you're binding to `{{amount}}` and `{{user}}` in your template, but these values are not changing in your code. They are only set in the constructor

Comment: which part of the angular code in the typescript loops then ? ngOnit is only executed once and the constructor also ?

Comment: What do you mean with loop?

Comment: you are coping my source and downvote to me. This is very bad. If you not apppreciate answer then pls dont downvote..

Comment: @KarnanMuthukumar, I'm not copying anything. You're creating a new `output` event, while I'm using the default event emitted by the component. Big difference

Comment: Then why you are not replyed before. Then Why you are downvoting to me.Its looks like very silly.

Comment: nvm i understood the code wrong. i tought the code is always looping and checking it if it has changed or not. this is not the case it just execute code if the event is emmited

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
<mat-slider 
  thumbLabel
  [displayWith]="formatLabel"
  tickInterval="auto"
  min="1"
  max="10"
 [(ngModel)]="value" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></mat-slider>
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ot9-p8kehb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: It is working.I have update above stackblitz link with your link.

Answer (score 0):

Html,

```
<mat-slider 
  thumbLabel
  [displayWith]="formatLabel"
  tickInterval="auto"
  (valueChange)="onChange($event)" <!--Here added New One for get value -->
  min="1"
  max="10"
  value="value"></mat-slider>
```

Ts,

```
import { Component,Output,EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Output() valueChange;
onChange(data){
    this.user = data;
    this.amount = this.user * 9;
}
```

Here is the output,
[image]

For more reference,
https://material.angular.io/components/slider/api
[image]

I know allready answered but here is way of doing proper way and also you have value in typescript you can use further.

I hope its useful,

Thanks,
Muthu

Comment: This is kind of overkill since the mat-slider is emitting these events, so need to declare them yourselve.

Comment: you are coping my source and downvote to me. This is very bad. If you not apppreciate answer then pls dont downvote

Comment: As already stated in previous comment. You're creating a new output which is not needed since the component is allready emitting this event. It makes no sense to create a new output event. But I'll remove the downvote for you're effort

Comment: I cannot remove downvote, if you make a small edit to your post I can

Comment: i upvoted this aswell because it works. But it does not show because my rep is to low